# Can you "win" Dwarf Fortress?

Tags: pc, dwarf-fortress

Can you "win" a game of Dwarf Fortress? Is there like an ending or some victory condition? Or does the game just go on forever sort of like The Sims?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Dwarf Fortress is a "[sandbox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_world)" game, like Minecraft.  Sandbox games typically have no set objectives and, yes, no *official* way to win them.

*Unofficial* ways to "win" would be along the lines of player-set goals or challenges like [these](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/40d:Challenges).

One could definitely consider a successful fort that accomplishes a major goal/challenge or two as "winning" the game, as you've likely mastered it by now, but you haven't *officially* won it, because doing so is impossible.

Comment: what do you mean by "official"? are there "unofficial" ways then since you're insinuating that there are?

Comment: "Unofficial" ways usually just include any goals the player sets for him or herself -- building some crazy structure, a fortress under the ocean, breaching the HFS and conquering the resulting... fun. Et cetera.

Comment: Ah, that's interesting. Is there a list of these somewhere?

Comment: @philthemustard [Here's a few](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/40d:Challenges).  They seem to be more challenges than goals, but should still be interesting.

Comment: I can't believe a good answer to this question doesn't mention FUN.